# Finding the first stream of non-repeating elements in Scala (without recursion or side-effects)

Tags: functional-programming, scala

Here are some examples:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5] => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[10, 15, 10, 15, 30] => [10, 15]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 5, 6, 7] => [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Here's my best (and deeply ugly) non-recursive, side-effect-free solution so far:

```
x.scanLeft(List[Int]())((B, Term) => Term :: B).drop(1).takeWhile(i => !(i.tail contains i.head)).last.reverse
```

Minor optimization:

```
x.tail.scanLeft(List(x.head))((B, Term) => Term :: B).takeWhile(i => !(i.tail contains i.head)).last.reverse
```

This is different from `distinct`:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 5, 6, 7] => [1, 2, 3, 4] and not [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

Also, considering `List[_]` is a monoid, isn't there a `scan` that uses the monoid `zero`?

Comment: You probably just want the `distinct` method... see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1538598/how-in-scala-to-find-unique-items-in-list

Answer (score 5):

This is a fold, not a scan. A scan produces something with the same number of elements, and change the elements. A fold produces something new.

```
def firstDistinct[T](s: Seq[T]) = s.foldLeft(Seq[T]() -> false) {
  case (result @ (_, true), _)           => result
  case ((seq, _), el) if seq contains el => seq -> true
  case ((seq, _), el)                    => (seq :+ el) -> false
}._1
```

Comment: Almost... Your solution doesn't work with "infinite" lists, while mine does. I know I didn't said that in the original post, but it's worth mentioning.

Comment: Nevertheless, amazing display of your functional-fu!

Comment: @HugoSFerreira Infinite lists are `Stream`, not `List`. Might first impulse _was_ going for `Stream`, but then I noticed you were restricting the solution to `List`... It should be doable with a lazy `foldRight`, which, iirc, Scala's isn't but Scalaz has.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on scalaz. I was already wrapping my head on why foldRight was being strict.

Answer (score 4):

```
def once(list:List[Int]) = {
  def go(acc:List[Int],set:Set[Int],rest:List[Int]):List[Int]=rest match{ 
    case x::xs if ! set(x) => go(x::acc, set + x, xs)
    case _ => acc.reverse 
  }
  go(Nil,Set(),list)
}
```

And the mandatory one-liner, which would be actually nice if `distinct` were supported on `List.view`:

```
list.zip(list.distinct).takeWhile{case(x,y) => x==y}.map(_._1)
```

**[Edit]**

There must be a nice one-liner for `Stream`s, too, but all I got so far is a train wreck...

```
st.scanLeft((Set[Int](),List[Int]()))((t,x) => if (t._1(x)) null else (t._1+x, x::t._2)).takeWhile(_ != null).last._2.reverse
```

**Edit 2**

Basically the same construction idea, but more readable:

```
st.zip(st.scanLeft(Set[Int]())(_+_)).takeWhile{case(x,s)=> !s(x)}.map(_._1)
```

Comment: Very nice your one-liner! I'll award the +50... but could you also solve it with infinite lists (streams)?

Answer (score 1):

```
    def first_distinct[T](x: Seq[T]) = {
        def iter(acc: Seq[T], met: Set[T], rest: Seq[T]): Seq[T] = {
            if (rest.isEmpty || (met contains rest.head)) acc
            else iter(acc :+ rest.head, met + rest.head, rest.tail)
        }
        iter(Vector.empty, Set.empty, x)
    }
```

This can be optimized, of course (but I'm not sure if compiler does this by itself). I'll write solution for lazy streams some time later.